# Android Camera Consumes airtime

Tags: android-camera

When I use my android phone after a while I find out that the camera has consumed a lot of data. If I forcestop the camera, it doesnt stop consuming. How can I stop my camera from consuming so much of the airtime by `downloading` many MB of data and why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

You probably see gallery synchronisation with picasa web albums.  Try to turn off sync in Gallery app and maybe also in google+ app.